# How to use variable with namespace in dataweave?

Tags: xml-namespaces, dataweave, mulesoft, anypoint-studio

There is a requirement where we need to use dynamic tag names in XML along with namespace. I am storing the tagname in a variable and trying to use with namespace.

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/XML encoding= "UTF-8"
%namespace opt vision.soap.ogc
%var tag = flowVars.tag
---
{
    opt#tag : 'something'
}
```

The output I am expecting is to be the tagname I have stored in variable along with namespace,  However the actual output is just appending the string 'tag' with namespace. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/XML encoding= "UTF-8"
%namespace opt vision.soap.ogc
%var tag = "a"
---
{
    opt#"$(tag)" : 'something'
}
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<opt:a xmlns:opt="vision.soap.ogc">something</opt:a>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Was struggling for quiet a while.